# requestLocationUpdates(), java.lang.RuntimeException - Android

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

So i have this error:

```
D/LocationManager: [LocationManager] requestLocationUpdates(), 
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:893)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:471)
        at com.cm.kami.cmproject.Distance.Distance.onCreate(Distance.java:95)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7027)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

When i use locationManager.requestLocationUpdates.

Here is the code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                    MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                    new MyLocationListener()
            );

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        }
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share MyLocationListener code?

Comment: have you find any solution??